# Is there a better way to initialize a list and add elements to it?

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if there is a better way or a more pythonic way to initialize an empty list and add elements to it?

The standard way:

```py
a = []  # or a = list()
a.append(elements)
```

Comment: `a = [elements]`

Comment: What is `elements`? And whats expected result? `[[1,2,3]]` or `[1,2,3]` ?

Comment: Using the * operator is way faster than the remaining methods. For detail overview check my answer. I think it should answer your question and solve your doubt.

Comment: Hey, so I realised that the quality of this question is very poor.
with ```elements``` I meant adding elements inside a for loop for example.

Comment: OK, I have added that to my answer

Comment: @GauravK see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to initialize an empty list:

1. In your case: `a = [elements]` if elements is a already a list
2. For a general case: `empty_a = [None] * 10`
3. For a general case: `empty_a = [0 for x in range(10)]`
4. For a general case: `empty_a = [[] for k in range(10)]`

---

**After you initialise the empty list you can use a for loop:**

```
empty_a = list() #or empty_a = [] OR empty_a = [[] for k in range(10)]
for i in range(10):
    empty.append(i)
```

**OR use list comprehension:**

```
empty_a = list()
[empty_a.append(i) for i in range(10)]
print(empty_a)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**These are the 2 standard pythonic ways to add elements to a list using a for loop.**

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative of `append` :-

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
my_list = [*my_list, 4]
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```